# Can one include already published papers in a monograph thesis?

Tags: phd, thesis, monograph

I am writing my phd thesis in a monograph format.

The monograph consists of several chapters, some of which have been published with co-authors, however, the thesis as a whole is a stand alone piece with each chapter connecting to the previous one and is on the same topic.

If I indicate that "part of this chapter are published in ..." but write the thesis a coherent whole, can it be considered as a monograph?

Comment: How did your advisor answer this question.  (You _did_ ask your advisor this question, didn't you?)

Comment: If the question is whether my co-authors agree that I include the chapters in my monograph the answer is yes. My question is about rules regarding the monograph. I cannot find any information on the internet about the specific rules of writing a monograph. What I would like to know is whether I can include chapters that were written with other people.

Comment: @gize The "specific rules of writing a monograph" differ from university to university, and sometimes even from department to department within a university. There is no general answer to this question. As it stands it's unanswerable because you don't state your university and department. (And if you did state your university and department, the question might be closed as being too specific.) You have to ask your advisor, or some other knowledgeable authority in your department or division.

Comment: Thank you @Pont for the answer. Let me rephrase it a bit then: what is your impression? Does your university accept this? Or is this considered to be standard practice? What is the definition of a monograph even?

Comment: **Ask your advisor.**

Comment: @gize (1) My impression is that there is no general rule. (2) I don't know whether my university would have accepted it, since I did not publish before submitting the thesis and thus never needed to ask, nor do I even know whether the policy would have been the same for all departments at the university. (3) I don't think it's standard practice, simply because as far as I know there *is* no standard practice. (4) As far as I know, there is no full and formal definition of the term "monograph" which is officially endorsed by all universities.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing Thesis: Copying from published papers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/128100/writing-thesis-copying-from-published-papers)

Answer (score 2):

This is common practice in a PhD thesis in the sciences.  Sometimes it is required that chapters in the thesis be published.

Comment: I understand that this is common practice for cumulative theses, but the question is whether it can also be done in a monograph if I integrate the chapters.